# talend connection with sql server 2008 R2 issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, talend, bigdata, database

I've been trying to connect with `SQL Server 2008` but I couldn't, and I'm getting the error below.  It says that : I have to check if the `TCP` port is blocked with a firewall...  well, no it's not !
what should I do ???

```
Echec de la connexion Vous devez modifier les paramètres de la base de données.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Échec de la connexion TCP/IP à l'hôte (local), port 1433. Erreur : « null. Vérifiez les propriétés de connexion. Assurez-vous qu'une instance de SQL Server est en cours d'exécution sur l'hôte et accepte les connexions TCP/IP au port. Vérifiez que les connexions TCP au port ne sont pas bloquées par un pare-feu. ».
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:195)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1092)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:315)
      at org.talend.metadata.managment.repository.ManagerConnection.check(ManagerConnection.java:289)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$62.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:3953)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$62.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:1)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$1.runnableWithCancel(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:77)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$ARunnableWithProgressCancel$1.call(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:161)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Échec de la connexion TCP/IP à l'hôte (local), port 1433. Erreur : « null. Vérifiez les propriétés de connexion. Assurez-vous qu'une instance de SQL Server est en cours d'exécution sur l'hôte et accepte les connexions TCP/IP au port. Vérifiez que les connexions TCP au port ne sont pas bloquées par un pare-feu. ».
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.DriverShim.connect(DriverShim.java:41)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:186)
      ... 9 more
```

Comment: How do you know it's not? Best thing to confirm is test with `telnet`

Comment: you are right bro, i did use this cmd netstat -aon   and it gave me several ports .. I've used one of them and boom it worked. thanks :)

Comment: today it's not working bro, I did check if my sql server is connected on a specific port 808 and it works. but always talend can'T get the conection :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem resolved , 
 Talend and SQL server are in the same machine so...
how I did it: on Sql server 
1 - server type :    database engine
2- server name :   127.0.0.1 
3- Authentication : Sql Server authentication
4- login :              sa
5- password :        *****   (any password you want )
then I went to Talend:
I did put the same specifications    ( specially the pass and login name)

Answer (score 0):

The connection may not work even if firewall is allowing the port traffic but the SQL server itself is not enabled for TCP/IP protocol.
Are able to connect to SQL server using other client tools using TCP/IP protocol? use SQL server configuration Manager to "Enable" the TCP/IP access.

Comment: id did that , TCP/ip protocol is allowed,  and also I did deactivate my antivirus and the firewall .... no connection !!!